# Foreign key violation when trying to insert into a table

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key

I have a table A and B in MARIADB. Please consider A as child of B and fk is ID. I am trying to insert value 15 to ID of A but a FK violation occurs.
error is similar to given below:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
>   ails ("A", CONSTRAINT "FK_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ID"
>   ) REFERENCES "B" ("ID")).

Problem is that B got the value 15 in its ID. So, there is no need for error to occur. 
Then i dropped the fk constraint and tried to create again. This time, i was not able to create a fk constraint.
Getting an error similar to given below:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
>   ails ("#sql-****_***", CONSTRAINT "FK_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ID"
>   ) REFERENCES "B" ("ID"))

I assume #sql-****_*** is a temporary table. Could anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Other useful info:
datatype is decimal(15,0)
engine is innodb.

SHOW CREATE TABLE A b4 dropping foreign key

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE "A" (
  "MD" decimal(15,0) NOT NULL,
  "RE" varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "GD" decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  "CK" varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "FC" varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "TC" varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "ME" varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "ID" decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL

  PRIMARY KEY ("MD"),
  UNIQUE KEY "UK_Y" ("TC","RE","ME","GD","FC"),
  KEY "FK_GD" ("GD"),
  KEY "FK_ID" ("ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_GD" FOREIGN KEY ("GD") REFERENCES "D" ("MID"),

  CONSTRAINT "FK_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ID") REFERENCES "B" ("ID")
)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE B

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE "B" (
  "ID" decimal(20,0) NOT NULL,
  "DE" varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "MY" varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "DDE" varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "CY" decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
  UNIQUE KEY "UE" ("DE"),
  UNIQUE KEY "AE" ("DDE"),
  KEY "FK_CPY" ("CY"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_CY" FOREIGN KEY ("CY") REFERENCES "X" ("MCY")
)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE A after dropping FK

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE "A" (
  "MD" decimal(15,0) NOT NULL,
  "RE" varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "GD" decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  "CK" varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "FC" varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "TC" varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "ME" varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "ID" decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL

  PRIMARY KEY ("MD"),
  UNIQUE KEY "UK_Y" ("TC","RE","ME","GD","FC"),
  KEY "FK_GD" ("GD"),
  KEY "FK_ID" ("ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_GD" FOREIGN KEY ("GD") REFERENCES "D" ("MID")
)
```

INSERT STATEMENT

```
INSERT  A (MD,
                                              RE,
                                              GD,
                                              CK,

                                              FC,
                                              TC,
                                              ME,
                                              ID
                                              )
                       VALUES (866,
                               'FILE',
                               NULL,
                               '',
                               '',
                               '',
                                '',
                               15
                              );
```

ORIGINAL show create table of child table

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `swift_mail_box` (
  `MAILBOX_ID` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL,
  `RECEIVE_MODE` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `GATEWAY_IN_ID` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMPLIANCE_CHECK` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `FROM_BIC` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `TO_BIC` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSG_TYPE` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `OWNER_ID` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FUNC_ID` decimal(15,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILTER_CHECK` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLIENT_ID` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTERPARTY_ID` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DISPLAY_PAGE` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_NEW` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CBR_ID` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPT_ID` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MAILBOX_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_SWIFT_MAIL_BOX` (`TO_BIC`,`RECEIVE_MODE`,`MSG_TYPE`,`GATEWAY_IN
_ID`,`FROM_BIC`,`CBR_ID`),
  KEY `FK_SWF_MAIL_GATEWAY_IN_ID` (`GATEWAY_IN_ID`),
  KEY `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_CBR_ID` (`CBR_ID`),
  KEY `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_COUNTERPARTY_ID` (`COUNTERPARTY_ID`),
  KEY `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_CLIENT_ID` (`CLIENT_ID`),
  KEY `FK_FUNCTION_ID` (`FUNC_ID`),
  KEY `FK_SW_MAIL_BOX_DEPT_ID` (`DEPT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FUNCTION_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`FUNC_ID`) REFERENCES `env_functions`
 (`FUNC_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SWF_MAIL_GATEWAY_IN_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`GATEWAY_IN_ID`) REFERENCE
S `connect_source_link` (`MRM_MDM_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_CBR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`CBR_ID`) REFERENCES `content_b
ased_routing` (`CBR_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_CLIENT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`CLIENT_ID`) REFERENCES `cli
ents` (`CLIENT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SWIFT_MAIL_COUNTERPARTY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`COUNTERPARTY_ID`) REF
ERENCES `counterparties` (`COUNTERPARTY_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SW_MAIL_BOX_DEPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`DEPT_ID`) REFERENCES `depart
ments` (`DEPT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Original show create of parent table

```
    Create Table: CREATE TABLE `corporate_divisions` (
  `OWNER_ID` decimal(20,0) NOT NULL,
  `DIVISION_NAME` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSG_CATEGORY` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `DIVISION_CODE` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `HIDDEN` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CATEGORY` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OWNER_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_CORP_DIV_NAME` (`DIVISION_NAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_CORP_DIV_CODE` (`DIVISION_CODE`),
  KEY `FK_COP_DIV_CATEGORY_ID` (`CATEGORY`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_COP_DIV_CATEGORY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`CATEGORY`) REFERENCES `messa
ge_category_list` (`MSG_CATEGORY_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Version of Mariadb used:10.3.13-MariaDB
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: So you haven't dropped the FK constraint. And why is the b.ID column decimal(20) while the a.ID is decimal(15)?

Comment: Hi, actually that didn't exist. I have manually added that one bec the real problem started when i tried to insert into A. I will edit the question once more.

Comment: Did you also create a TEMPORARY table with the same name (A)?

Comment: No, i didn't create  any temp table but i created a view A in another DB(To implement synonym concept). I have already deleted that table

Comment: Added original statements as well as version of mariadb and os

Comment: Thank you, good. Can you try changing that OWNER_ID to match the decima(20) of the referenced column (and then recreate the FK)? If that doesn't fix it, then it might be a bug or setup issue with MariaDB on Windows.

Comment: If the table (A) has no data, you could also drop it and recreate it from scratch (this might help in case there is some corruption in the system tables and an FK has not been properly dropped).

Comment: Thank you, Problem is solved when i changed datatype of child table's OWNER_ID to match the decimal(20,0) of the referenced column .

Comment: 1:1 mapping between two tables is usually a schema design error.  It is usually better to use some size of `INT` for integers, not `DECIMAL(..,0)`.